# Правильно ли записано это предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, и, цитата

*Единственный хоть каким-то боком похожий афоризм звучит так: «Не делай ничего дурного даже в темноте», и обычно трактуется как требование давить дурные мысли в зародыше.*

Предложение из статьи «[Служба испорченных цитат: Конфуций о кошке в темной комнате](https://dzen.ru/a/XLV4SnpDIgCz0-fz)».

Меня интересует отсутствие возможной запятой перед «хоть» и правомерность постановки запятой перед союзом «и». Желательно с обоснованием.

Спасибо.

Comment: Единственный, хоть каким-то боком похожий афоризм, звучит так: "Котфуций", - и...

Comment: Вы хотите поставить запятую и тире. А почему? Как вы делаете выбор (грамматика, смысл, интонация)?

Comment: Продолжение фразы после прямой речи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбор этого предложения снова может привести к долгим спорам. Я же предлагаю не рассматривать строго данную пунктуацию, потому что... гладиолус.

#### Об отсутствии запятой перед «хоть»

*Единственный **хоть каким-то боком похожий** афоризм звучит так...*

Думаю, «хоть» здесь является частицей: «То же, что «хотя бы». Не требует постановки знаков препинания» ([Академик](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/712/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C)).
К частице «хоть/хотя» всегда можно добавить «бы», что невозможно сделать с союзом «хотя».
К тому же мы не поставим запятую в таком случае: *Единственный похожий афоризм*. Так как определения неоднородны.
Если всё-таки в силу интонации просится запятая, то для соблюдения грамматики нужна и вторая:
*Единственный, **хоть каким-то боком похожий,** афоризм звучит так.*
Но тогда оборот уходит на второй план, что не соответствует основному смыслу высказывания. Это не уточнение и не пояснение. А одна запятая возможна только в случае однородности.

#### О знаке перед союзом «и»

Вы говорите о возможности трёх вариантов.
Стандартный случай – **тире**. Да, всё по правилу.
**Запятая с тире** мне здесь не нравится: слишком, что ли, большая оторванность получается между первой и последней частями, а они же не конкурируют, не противопоставляются, и нет никакого «перелома» конструкции.
А вот одна **запятая** вроде бы нормально. Это похоже на запятую перед присоединительным союзом «и», когда можно и точку поставить. Такое ощущение, что этому способствует слово «так».
*Афоризм звучит **так**: «...», и трактуется...* Для такого случая и правило есть («по условиям контекста»).

Есть ещё четвёртый вариант, «бесправильный». Зачем вообще там какой-то знак? Ведь кавычки показывают конец цитаты. :)

#### О самой статье

Автор – Вадим Нестеров, журналист и писатель.
Я прочитал эту небольшую статью. Она, безусловно, написана грамотно. Но мой придирчивый взгляд всё же зацепился за:

**1.** *Среднестатистический россиянин если что и знает про Конфуция, так разве что изречение «Очень трудно искать черную кошку в темной комнате, особенно, если там ее нет».*
Не думаю, что нужна запятая после «особенно».
[**ОСОБЕННО,** *наречие*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_511) (Грамота.ру): «*Хуже нет – иметь дело с шифоньерами, особенно если в комнате спит человек.* Ф. Искандер, Рассказы о Чике».

**2.** *И это уже много лет буквально бомбит китаеведов, не устающих посылать лучи ненависти братьям Вайнерам, придумавшим эту фразу и создателям сериала «Место встречи изменить нельзя»...*
Нет запятой после причастного оборота «придумавшим эту фразу».

**3.** *Впоследствии эта фраза Ден Сяопина стала неофициальным девизом китайских реформ 1980-90 годов.*
Между годами дожно стоять тире, а не дефис. Мелочь, конечно. А где наращение ***-х***? Тоже мелочь, но, извините, неаккуратно как-то...

**4.** *В этом отрывке Ленин напоминает товарищу по партии «афоризм Конфуция: самое трудное – поймать кошку в темной комнате, особенно тогда, когда ее там нет».*
Открывающие кавычки не на том месте.

**5.** *Эту мудрость Ильич – т.е., собственно, Сартаков, – почерпнул отнюдь не из трактата Конфуция...*
Зачем стоит запятая перед вторым тире?

**Один из отзывов** на книги автора:
«Местами видны редакторские недоработки... Можно посоветовать сделать дополнительную вычитку текста».

**P. S.** Ох, Sharon, Вам надо было бы разбить вопрос на два... Помните, три в одном было: двоеточие перед именем, объяснить про кличку и там.

Answer (score 2):

Что касается постановки запятой после прямой речи.

---

Считаю, что тут ошибка, т.к. есть такое правило:

> Тире ставится в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва
> вводящих слов автора: Перебарывая неловкость, он **пробормотал**
> студенческую остроту: «У меня бабушка корью заболела» – и **хотел**
> **придать** начатому разговору непринужденную легковесность (Бонд.);

В данном случае **запятая не нужна** (тире, например, нужно), т.к. "и" связывает однородные сказуемые **"звучит"** и **"трактуется"**.

---

По первому вопросу не буду высказываться, замечу лишь, что интонационный рисунок данного предложения не располагает к постановке запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Но сомнения все-таки остаются. В общем случае перед И возможны три знака: запятая, тире и запятая и тире, и я пока допускаю возможность всех вариантов (по смыслу, грамматике и интонации).  Вы выбрали стандартное решение, но другие не исключаются. Что касается запятой перед"хоть", то там тоже те же проблемы (то ли есть пауза, то ли нет), да и грамматику надо объяснять. Давайте подождем другие ответы.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу Александра**

**Спасибо!!**

Ох уж эти редакторы, я к ним отношусь «опасливо». Все буковки проверят (даже не слова!), все дефисы пересчитают… Нет житья от них нашему писательскому племени! Писателю важно обозначить силу мысли, красочность образов, а тут – «всякие мелочи, а то неаккуратно». Иногда даже думается: «Ах! Тому, кто редактор – писателем не стать!»

**А теперь о главном))**

**Об отсутствии запятой перед «хоть»**

*Единственный хоть каким-то боком похожий афоризм звучит так…*

Определения **неоднородные**? Может быть, и так… С другой стороны: единственный афоризм, хоть каким-то боком похожий афоризм. Тогда это **однородные** определения. Но тогда и третий вариант возможен (с уточнением):  *Единственный, хоть каким-то боком похожий, афоризм…*

**Софистика**, одним словом… Тогда можно сделать **выбор по структуре**: оборот распространённый,  так что лучше его обособить. Форма разрешенная,  см.Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118 пункт 4

**А что там с интонацией** (интонационный рисунок, как говорит Ajgy, хороший, между прочим, термин)?

Прочтение  такое: ***Единственный  / хоть каким-то боком похожий  /  афорИзм  / / звучит тАк…*** (Объяснить интонацию могу (здесь непростой случай), но не хочу затемнять тему вопроса))

**О знаке перед союзом «и»**

*Единственный хоть каким-то боком похожий афоризм звучит так: «Не делай ничего дурного даже в темноте», и обычно трактуется как требование давить дурные мысли в зародыше.*

Стандартный вариант – это **тире**. Но почему автор поставил **запятую?** Неграмотный, неаккуратный? Кто его знает, а вдруг это сознательный выбор.
Присоединительная запятая? Да, похоже. Возможно, он хотел разделить фразу на два сообщения, а стандартное тире при отсутствии знаков перед союзом И его не устроило.

С другой стороны,  **универсальный знак** «запятая и тире» вполне здесь хорош. Конструкцию хочется разделить на две части и увеличенной паузой, и понятным письменным знаком. **Из комментария**: Продолжение фразы после прямой речи? – Буратино.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146994/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Тире с запятой используется в особых случаях. Они перечислены у Розенталя, хоть и невнятно. Оно не тупо для увеличения паузы, как и двоеточие.

Comment: В общем я бы определил Кибернетику, как науку об управлении совокупными системами через манипуляцию со значимыми языковыми единицами. https://trends.rbc.ru/trends/industry/615408c89a7947ec46f24aff "Термин «кибернетика» ввел Платон как науку управления особыми объектами, имеющими в своем составе людей - эти объекты он называл «гиберно». Это могла быть и административная единица - земля, заселенная людьми, и корабль. По Платону, построенный и снаряженный корабль - это просто вещь, а вот корабль с экипажем - это уже «гиберно», которым должен управлять специалист - «кибернет»."

Comment: @oleedd С помощью языка задается объектное или объективное пространство, со своими правилами, и акторы начинают существовать в этом пространстве через принцип обратной связи, определяющий субъект-объектные отношения. Вот это примерно то, ради чего придумана семантика и куда это идет.

Comment: @Буратино Вы опять ударились в философию. Я в этом не силён, мне близка конкретика (конкретные случаи). Лучше это в чат переместить, здесь должно быть только то, что касается ответа.

Comment: @oleedd это уже не совсем философия, это практическая философия, не что это, а как это работает. Как работает семантика, например. Однако, кибернетика это то, что лежит в основе принципа, а принцип применяется в науке в целом, а не только в семантике, определяет развитие науки в определенном направлении. Принцип - это очень конкретная схема. Конкретнее, чем принцип вряд ли что-то можно придумать.

Comment: Способ (метод) конкретнее, чем принцип.

Comment: @oleedd ладно не суть, спор не о чем. Вот это посмотри лучше) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6LacqAFlQg